# C - Using a user input file name

Tags: c

I've ran into a problem trying to open a file from user input. I can open it if the filename is correct the first time it's entered, but can't if it's correct in the while loop.

```
    char file[256], *end;
printf("Enter the name of the file: ");
fgets(file, 256, stdin);
if((end=strchr(file, '\n'))!=NULL)
    *end='\0';
FILE *fp=fopen(file, "r");
while(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("The given file doesn't exist. Enter a file name: ");
    fgets(file, 256, stdin);
    if((end=strchr(file, '\n'))!=NULL)
        *end='\0';
    FILE *fp=fopen(file, "r");
}
```

Comment: You just exit if the file doesnt exit. Why do you want to ask repeatedly, The given file doesn't exist. Enter a file name: `??

Comment: @xing thanks, that solved it:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can open it if the filename is correct the first time it's entered, but can't if it's correct in the while loop.

No, you're being fooled.  The problem is that the loop condition in `while(fp==NULL)` tests the value of variable `fp` declared *outside* the loop, and inside the loop you never set that variable, so if you enter the loop you will never exit.

But that doesn't mean you fail to open the file on the second attempt or a subsequent one.  Inside the loop, you declare *another* variable `fp`, "shadowing" the one outside, and assign the result of `fopen()` to it.  When this `fopen()` succeeds, you effectively ignore the result.

As another, now deleted, answer said, the main thing to do is to fix the loop so that it uses the same `fp` that is used outside.  The smallest change that achieves that would yield this version of the loop:

```
while(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("The given file doesn't exist. Enter a file name: ");
    fgets(file, 256, stdin);
    if((end=strchr(file, '\n'))!=NULL)
        *end='\0';
    fp=fopen(file, "r");
}
```

There are some other issues with the way you input the file name, both there and in the code preceding, as well as some unnecessary code duplication, but as long as the file names entered by the user are simple and short, that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider about the platform here, to make it your code cross platform file check the approach is different. If the platform is not important then you dont need to worry about Windows, in Linux you can use [stat utility](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Simple way to check the existence of file(Checks in read-mode) :

```
int read_file_exists(const char *filename)
{
   FILE *fp = fopen (filename, "r");
   if (fp!=NULL) fclose (fp);
   return (fp!=NULL);
}
```

Check this link for more information about [C file check.](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-file-exists/)

Comment: Why, exactly, is it supposed to be better to check whether the file exists separately from trying to open it?  A function such as you present might make sense if you only want to check the file's existence, but it's needless if you're going to go ahead and (re)open the file in the event that it does exist.

Comment: From the OP, printf, it spits _file doesn't exist_, so I presume that he just want to do file existence check, that is why I thought its much efficient to check the existence of file in the separate function.

Comment: The OP says straight away "I've ran into a problem trying to open a file from user input," so it doesn't seem much of a stretch to conclude that he indeed does want to open the file.  That he doesn't present any of what he wants to do once he's opened it is *good*.  We don't need to see that to address the question.

Comment: This code tests if the file exists by the ability to open it in read-mode.  Files may exist, yet are not open-able for a variety of reasons.  `FileExists()` is a misleading function name.

Comment: Ok, I will correct the name of function. It just test can open in read-mode